# exposes a Remote client view. This feature is not part of the EJB 3.1 Lite API

Tags: ejb, glassfish-3

Glassfish v3 gives this exception " exposes a Remote client view. This feature is not part of the EJB 3.1 Lite API" when I deploy the jar file.

I tried with Java EE 6 Web Profile SDK and Java EE 6 SDK but there is no difference.

I think there is a easy solution about configuration but what is the solution? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem, thanks.

Use the update tool which comes with glassfish installation.

Under the Available addons node, Install "Glassfish Commons Full Profile".
Restart the glassfish, done. :)
Deployment will be success.