# Can EJB 3.1 Lite be exposed via Remote interface?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

So I have written an application Expose my business logic via Remote interface for App Client, and Local interface for Web module. Just find out that our server has limited memory, so I need to make Glassfish to be light weight. Unfortunately, GF Full Profile is not light weight (using GF 3.1.1 RC atm), therefore I am looking at the Web profile of GlassFish. Now there is a answer saying that Remote interface is not a feature of EJB Lite here ( [exposes a Remote client view. This feature is not part of the EJB 3.1 Lite API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301875/exposes-a-remote-client-view-this-feature-is-not-part-of-the-ejb-3-1-lite-api) ), but it was 7 months ago, and the OP answered his/her own question, so I just want to confirm this information.

If it is true the Remote interface is not for the web profile, then is there a way for me to make Glassfish lighter? I dont need a lot of feature from Glassfish full profile, like JAX-WS, JAXB, JAX-RS ... Can I take them out somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per table 27 of the EJB 3.1 spec, remote interfaces are not part of EJB Lite ("Local / No-interface: YES", "3.0 Remote: NO", "2.x Remote Home/Component: NO")

(Sorry, I don't know enough about Glassfish to answer your other question.)